Accumulated sum hours power query
After many attempts the code still does not give the result of a cumulative summary of the hours for each employee
I would appreciate any help in finding the error
let
    Source = let
       EmployeeName = {"EMP-1", "EMP-1", "EMP-1", "EMP-1", "EMP-1", "EMP-1", "EMP-1", "EMP-2", "EMP-2", "EMP-2", "EMP-2", "EMP-2", "EMP-2", "EMP-2"},
    DayOfWeek = {"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"},
    Date = {"01/03/2024", "02/03/2024", "03/03/2024", "04/03/2024", "05/03/2024", "06/03/2024", "07/03/2024", "01/03/2024", "02/03/2024", "03/03/2024", "04/03/2024", "05/03/2024", "06/03/2024", "07/03/2024"},
    IN = {null, null, "09:05", "08:20", "09:30", null, "09:35", null, null, "09:15", "08:40", "09:50", "10:20", "09:55"},
    OUT = {null, null, "19:25", "18:30", "14:50", null, "16:45", null, null, "16:38", "18:10", "15:30", "12:50", "14:15"},
    HoursWorked = {"00:00", "00:00", "10:20", "10:10", "05:20", "07:10", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00", "07:23", "09:30", "05:40", "02:30", "04:20"},
    Status = {"WeekEnd", "WeekEnd", null, null, null, "Holiday", null, "WeekEnd", "WeekEnd", null, null, null, null, null},

       Table = Table.FromColumns({EmployeeName, DayOfWeek, Date, IN, OUT, HoursWorked, Status}, type table [EmployeeName=text, DayOfWeek=text, Date=text, IN=text, OUT=text, HoursWorked=text, Status=text])
in
    Table,
    GroupedRows = Table.Group(Source, {"EmployeeName"}, {{"Emp", each _, type table [EmployeeName=text, DayOfWeek=text, Date=text, IN=text, OUT=text, HoursWorked=text, Status=text]}}),
    NumToTime = (TimeCol as number) as text =>

let
    
hours = Number.RoundDown(24 * TimeCol),

minutes = Number.Round(60 * Number.Round((24 * TimeCol - hours) * 10000) / 10000),

 FrmtTime = Text.Combine({Text.From(hours), ":", 
                         Text.PadStart(Text.From(minutes), 2, "0")})
in
    FrmtTime,

    AddIndexToTable = Table.AddColumn(GroupedRows, "iEmp", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Emp], "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)),
  
    AddNewColumn = Table.AddColumn(AddIndexToTable, "nEmp", each Table.AddColumn([iEmp], "nHours", each [Hours Worked])),

    AddedCustom = Table.AddColumn(AddNewColumn, "TmpSum", each Table.AddColumn( [nEmp] , "Running Total", each List.Sum( List.Range( [nEmp], [nHours], 0, [Index] ) ))),

    Custom2 = Table.AddColumn(AddedCustom, "FinalTmpSum", each Table.AddColumn([TmpSum], "Running Total (Hours:Minutes)", each NumToTime([TmpSum][Running Total])))
in
    Custom2


You could add it into the grouping
Instead, as a separate step after the grouping you could Add column .... custom column ...
= Table.AddColumn([A], "Running Total (Hours:Minutes)", each MyNumToTime([A][Running Total]))


Maybe someone has an idea how to solve this?
What's wrong with my code?
